# PHP Str_replace image type

Tags: php, str-replace

I have an XML weather feed for an application. The feed is sending out information for .GIF images but I want it to look for .PNG. I tried a STR_REPLACE but it did not work.

```
 $icon = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions/icon");

   $iconData = str_replace('.gif','.png',$icon);

  echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images'.$iconData[2]->attributes().'" />';
```

A little more info :::

The images are not provided by the XML feed. Just the beginning of the URL for them. So the output from the XML Feed for `$icon[1]` say is `ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif` . I have then added our URL at the beginning and set up the same path but I just need the .gif to change to .png

ECHO $icon[1] after the first line is `ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif` That is all.

Comment: huh?  is it an external source providing the feed/images?

Comment: Not the images. Just the beginning of the URL for them. So the output from the XML Feed for $icon[1] say is ig/images/weather/mostly_sunny.gif . I have then added our URL at the beginning and set up the same path but I just need the .gif to change to .png

Comment: If you `echo $icon` after the first line, what is the output? It might be helpful if you knew / provided that info.

Answer (score 1):

You've got lots of stuff going on here, it's a hard to predict what might happen.

```
$icon = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions/icon");
```

At this point, `$icon` is an array, possibly empty, of SimpleXMLObject objects.

```
$iconData = str_replace('.gif','.png',$icon);
```

`str_replace` can accept an array as the third argument, it's *possible* that it also coerces the values in `$icon` in to strings.  The result of this is dependent on the structure of your XML, if the `icon` elements are always text this should be OK.

```
echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images'.$iconData[2]->attributes().'" />'
```

Does this work at all?  I would have thought that, at this point, $iconData would be an array of strings, not an array of SimpleXMLObject objects.

If I were you I'd manually iterate the results of the xpath search and explicitly cast SimpleXMLObject objects to strings as an when I needed them to behave as strings.

HTH.

Comment: This doesn't do anything. The image remains a gif. I did state that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$iconData = str_replace('.gif','.png',$icon[1]);
echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/'.$iconData.'" />'
```

So you're sure the folder on your side is this 'stylesheet_directory' PLUS /images PLUS the /ig/images/weather ?

I think the original problem is that str_replace is for strings and you passed in an array?..